# a definite log-sin integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, logarithms

I am wondering if there is a way to solve this definite integral depicted below:

$$\int_0^1 \log(-\log(x)\sin(x))\text{d}x.$$

[image: plot of integral]

Mathematica numerically evaluates this integral to $-1.63394$. I am not experienced with these types of integrals and have tried approaches in related questions with no success. Thanks.

Comment: i think the result should be this here $$-\gamma -\frac{1}{12} i \left(-6 \text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i}\right)+6+(\pi -6) \pi -12 i \log(2)\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: *you* think or *Mathematica* thinks? In the second case, your comment is kind of irrelevant, anyone is able to type such integral in a CAS. It would be more honest to write *according to Mathematica* or something like that.

Comment: $\sin(1)$ is a rather meaningless expression. A much more interesting evaluation would have been that of $$\int_0^1\ln\bigg(-\ln x~\sin\bigg(\frac\pi2~x\bigg)\bigg)~dx.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may first write
$$
\int_0^1 \log(-\log(x)\sin(x))\:dx=\int_0^1 \log(-\log(x))\:dx+\int_0^1 \log(\sin(x))\:dx
$$ The first integral on the right hand side can be handled by the change of variable $\displaystyle t=-\log(x)$ giving
$$
\int_0^1 \log(-\log(x))\:dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log(t)\:dt=-\gamma
$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). The last integral, via the identity $2i\sin x=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$, gives
$$
\int_0^1 \log(\sin(x))\:dx=-\log (2)-\frac{1}{2} \Im\left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i}\right)\right).
$$